# Не отображается цвет текста в TextView на реальном устройстве

Tags: java, android, textview, color

Я недавно занялась программирование в Android Studio и столкнулась с такой проблемой:
Использовав ConstrainLayout на фрагменте я добавила TextView, где записала некоторые слова, цвет которых изменила в string

`<string name="purpure"><font color="#c16e7b"> Мой фиолетовый текст </font></string>`

Но, запустив мое приложение на реальном смартфоне, цвет моего текста поменялся на белый.

Я уже пыталась объявлять нужные мне цвета в colors.xml, а в string.xml выводить только их названия. Пробовала и другие методы, найденные в интернете, но ничего не помогла.

Да и идентичной проблемы на форумах не видела.

Я буду крайне(!) благодарна за любую подсказку.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Less1"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_less1">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="518dp"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/purpure"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: в блоке TextView указывается цвет текста: `android:textColor="@color/purple"`. в colors.xml должен быть определен какой то цвет с именем purple –

Comment: а если, внезапно, хотите что бы ваш способ заработал, надо "сказать" вашему textView в коде что вы передаете ему не простую строку, а html:
findviewbyId(R.id.textView).setText(Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.app_name)))
(но чаще всего не надо так делать)

Comment: Да, это я знаю. Но суть в том, что у меня достаточно большой текст, слова которого надо сделать разными цветами. А Ваш способ подходит лишь для всего текста

Comment: Тогда более правильным решением будет использовать Spannable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android
Для каждого отрывка текста делаем setSpan с указанием начала и конца текста, конечный Spannable вставляем в textview